# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: В описании продукта нет информации сколько кусков будет в упаковке

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

В описании продукта нет информации сколько кусков будет в упаковке.
Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, с ответом на мой вопрос. Нужна ли запятая после слова информации? окк поставили ошибку, что это спп и нужна запятая.

Comment: напишите так: В описании продукта нет информации о количестве кусков в упаковке. А там вроде нужна запятая.

Comment: Придаточное предложение, вводимое союзом сколько, отделяется запятой.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я уже ответила таким предложением. Теперь спорим нужна ли запятая именно в этом предложении: В описании продукта нет информации сколько кусков будет в упаковке.

Comment: @ВикторияМаслова Вам помог мой ответ? Вы до сих пор его не приняли.

Answer (score 2):

**Запятая нужна.**

***В описании продукта нет информации, сколько кусков будет в упаковке.***

Придаточное предложение ***сколько кусков будет в упаковке*** нужно отделить запятой от главной части.